# Finding the smooth curve of minimum length between two points with some constraints

Tags: calculus, optimization, definite-integrals

I have been struggling with this problem for a while. Pretty sure this can be done with out using calculus of variations as we haven't covered these, yet. Here is the complete problem :

> Find the smooth curve $g(x)$ of minimum length between points
>   $(10,10)$ and $(30,0)$ such that
>   1) $g'(10)=1$
>   2) $\int\limits_{10}^{30}g(x)\,dx=200$
>   3) $g(x)\ge 0$ for $x\in (10,30)$

My attempt :
I have assumed $g(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and found [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arc%20length%20g%28x%29%3D-0.075x%5E2%2B2.5x-7.5%2C%2010..30) curve which meets all the given constraints except one : It is not of minimum length.
I am kinda stuck. Not sure what else to try... Any help in finding the curve of minmum length is highly appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A priori there's no reason to think the solution should be of the form you suggest.  Here's one possible approach (although this is basically the idea behind calculus of variations).  Suppose we have a solution $g$.  Consider a small perturbation $g+\epsilon h$, where $\epsilon$ is small and $h$ is a smooth function with $h(10)=h(30)=h'(10)=0$ and $\int_{10}^{30} h = 0$ (so the perturbed curve still has the correct end-points and satisfies conditions (1) and (2)).

Since $g$ minimises the arc length, the length of the perturbed curve must be minimised at $\epsilon=0$.  Hence

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\epsilon}\bigg|_{\epsilon=0} \int_{10}^{30} \sqrt{1+(g+\epsilon h)'^2} \ \mathrm{d}x = 0.$$

Taking the derivative inside the integral we get

$$\int_{10}^{30} \frac{g'h'}{\sqrt{1+g'^2}} \ \mathrm{d}x = 0.$$

Integrating by parts we then see that

$$\int_{10}^{30} \Bigg(\frac{g'}{\sqrt{1+g'^2}}\bigg)' h \ \mathrm{d}x = 0.$$

This must hold for all smooth perturbations $h$ satisfying the above conditions.  By taking $h$ to be appropriate bump functions, this is only possible if

$$\Bigg(\frac{g'}{\sqrt{1+g'^2}}\bigg)'$$

is constant.

One can now solve this by an appropriate trig substitution to see that the solution curve is an arc of a circle.

Answer (score 1):

The curve of minimum length, enclosing together with the segment $AB$ ($A$ and $B$ are the two given points) an area of $100$, is an arc of a circle. We see here an instance of Dido's problem. There is no simple proof that a circular arc is optimal.

Whether the optimal arc (you can easily compute it) has the prescribed tangential direction at $A$ remains to be seen. If not, the problem has no solution, but you can find a minimizing sequence of curves fulfilling all conditions.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the problem has no solution if the tangent is not correct at $A$? Is it because we can make arbitrarily small corrections to the arc in order to get the correct tangent?

Comment: And another point. Sure, a circle minimizes length for a given area, but this is not guaranteed to be a function of $x$, which the question is about. Specifically, if the required area is large compared to the line segment, the arc must "bulge" at the endpoints.